# How do I hook up a Node/React application to a remote Informix server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, informix

I'm trying to make a containerized React app that needs to talk to a remote Informix box every once in a while, and it's been a PITA so far.

I've tried all of these packages (https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=informix), and they all seem to be built to connect to a local Informix instance.

Additionally, they all tend to throw 'Could not locate the bindings file.' errors.

```
[dev:server] /Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88
  err = new Error('Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:\n'
        ^
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/build/odbc_bindings.node
 → /Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/build/Debug/odbc_bindings.node
 → /Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/build/Release/odbc_bindings.node
 → /Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/out/Debug/odbc_bindings.node
 → /Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/Debug/odbc_bindings.node
 → /Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/out/Release/odbc_bindings.node
 → /Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/Release/odbc_bindings.node
 → /Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/build/default/odbc_bindings.node
 → /Users/whatevern/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/compiled/6.10.0/darwin/x64/odbc_bindings.node
    at bindings (/Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/node_modules/ibm_db/lib/odbc.js:27:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/whatever/dev/rubix/redux/redux-todolist/tmp/webpack:/external "ibm_db":1:1)
[dev:server] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Does anybody have any input, or is Informix just a little too old and specific to hook into a Node app easily?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the node driver for Informix
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ifx_db
Please see the example given, and update the connection string parameter for your remote host. 
Please let me know if you get any problem.